# SQL Query, how to return elements not in other 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

here is my data

movies table:

```
id title
10 Promise Land
13 Alive
14 Bruce Almighty
15 Decay
19 Malcom X
```

users table:

```
id username
1  Franck
2  Matt
```

archive table:

```
userid movieid
1      13
2      14
1      14
```

I'd like to get all the movies.id, movies.title that are not in the archive table for user id = 1.
I want to use JOINS (I don't want a select of select)

result should be:

```
id title
10 Promise Land
15 Decay
19 Malcom X
```

the following SQL fails:

```
SELECT a.id,a.title 
FROM db.movies AS a
LEFT JOIN db.archive AS b ON a.id = b.movieid
LEFT JOIN db.users AS c ON c.id = b.userid
WHERE b.movieid IS NULL OR b.userid !=1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using JOINS. You put the userid filter into the JOIN

```
SELECT
    a.id,a.title 
FROM
    binews.movies AS a
    LEFT JOIN
    binews.archive AS b ON a.id = b.movieid AND b.userid <> 1
WHERE
    b.movieid IS NULL;
```

However, you are actually asking "give my movies where they don't exists for this user in the archive table)

```
SELECT
    a.id,a.title 
FROM
    binews.movies AS a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM
             binews.archive AS b
          WHERE
             a.id = b.movieid AND b.userid <> 1);
```

This is more correct generally. In some cases you'll get multiple rows from a LEFT JOIN where a userid has used the same more than once. To correct this, you'll need DISTINCT which adds processing.

However, EXISTS removes this multiple row output.

See this for more: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: no, this query returns 
10 Promise Land
13 Alive
15 Decay
19 Malcom X

Comment: @gbn  should be AND b.user.id=1  in order to get the result correct. I was missing the fact I could filter in the JOIN so your answer guided me well. Thanks. Please correct your post if you have a minute

Answer (score 1):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use option with EXISTS and [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.movies
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT id
              EXCEPT
              SELECT movieid
              FROM archive
              WHERE userid = 1
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91f48/1)

**OR** option with NOT EXISTS AND [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.movies
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                            
                  SELECT movieid
                  FROM archive
                  WHERE userid = 1
                  INTERSECT 
                  SELECT id
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91f48/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from binews.movies 
      where id not in(select movieid from binews.archive where userid<>1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to gbn. here is the solution with a correction "AND b.userid=1"

```
SELECT
    a.id,a.title 
FROM
    binews.movies AS a
    LEFT JOIN
    binews.archive AS b ON a.id = b.movieid AND b.userid=1
WHERE
b.movieid IS NULL
```